# Quarried Stones in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How do I get the quarried stone for my house in Skyrim? I've found the mines for it, but after I mine I don't receive any of the stones.

Comment: it's unlimited mining for 4000 units per month. I guess what you're doing is bugged out.

Answer (score 2):

Quarried stone and clay can be found in small infinite deposits near the location you are building your home.

[The wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Quarried_Stone) has a full list of where you can find these deposits.

Stone deposit:

[image]